# How to use variable from envirinment inside body request in Postman?

Tags: json, rest, postman

I have simply defined two variables:

[image]

And now I am going to use it inside my request body:

[image]

but it doesn't work. Why?

When I enter my values as a string it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

postman variables simply resolves to its value , it doesn't differentiate it self as string,number etc . You have to make the decision.

so if a variable as value "test" then :

```
{

"key":{{var}}

}
```

resolves to

```
{

"key":test

}
```

which is not a valid json , as strings most be enclosed **with double quotes (single quotes not supported in json)**

### solution:

**First approach:**

enclose all strings with double quotes:

```
{

"key":"{{var}}"

}
```

**second approach**

pass the quotes in value is self:

set value as

```
pm.environment.set("var",'"test"')
```

amd im body use without quotes:

```
{

"key":{{var}}

}
```

this resolves to :

```
{

"key":"test"

}
```